# Python-OBD module object has no attribute "OBD"

Tags: python, obd-ii

Having problem in bootstrapping my OBD scanner using python-obd library. I'm more of a Ruby guy, new to python. Doing the python-obd's tutorial code and terminal answers this:

```
 File "car.py", line 2, in <module>
    import obd
  File "/Users/aabulkhairov/Development/publicobd/obd.py", line 3, in     <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OBD'
```

Do i have to find the obd.py file and copy it to this file's folder?

Here's the car.py:

```
import obd

connection = obd.OBD() # auto-connects to USB or RF port

cmd = obd.commands.SPEED # select an OBD command (sensor)

response = connection.query(cmd) # send the command, and parse the response

print(response.value) # returns unit-bearing values thanks to Pint
print(response.value.to("mph")) # user-friendly unit conversions
```

Comment: "Do i have to find the obd.py file and copy it to this file's folder?" No and since your import works then I'm guessing you correctly installed with `pip`? You didn't call one of your own files `obd.py` did you?

Comment: Yeah, i correctly did "pip install obd" and it went fine. Also no, i have only one file named "car.py" in my working directory

Comment: Oh i found issue :) At first i called file "obd.py" then renamed to "car.py". But  the file "obd.pyc" was generated - removed it and script worked fine! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

One thing I learned is that you shouldn't name your (test) Python file:

```
obd.py
```

And then start with a search of the available ports:

```
ports = obd.scan_serial()      # return list of valid USB or RF ports
```